# How to copy 2d String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm having difficulty copying string array values into a new string array.

For example:

```
String[][] array = new String[3][2];
array[0][0] = "hello";
array[0][1] = "1";
array[1][0] = "guys";
array[1][1] = "2";
array[2][0] = "good ";
array[2][1] = "3";

array = new String [5][2];
all the value in the first array to be copied
array[3][0] = "";
array........;
```

I tried this method but it keeps me giving null pointer issues whenever I want to insert a new value.

```
String[][] array = new String[3][2];
array[0][0] = "olo";
array[0][1] = "ada ";
array[1][0] = "apa";
array[1][1] = "dengan";
array[2][0] = "si ";
array[2][1] = "carlo";


String[][] newArray = new String[5][2];
newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, 5);
array = new String[5][2];
array = Arrays.copyOf(newArray, 5);
array[3][0] = "lo";
array[3][1] = "gw";
array[4][0] = "end";
array[4][1] = "ennnnnd";

for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[r][c]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

How can I copy this 2d string array?

Answer (score 9):

Java has a built in function called [arraycopy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) that can do this for you without a double for loop.  Much more efficient.

Comment: You still have to call arraycopy for the second dimension items. right?

Comment: btw how to call the second dimmension for copying

Answer (score 1):

First of all the newer array has more elements that source array so decide what you want to do about it. Also if old array is called **array** call the new array by a different name say **newarray**.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
  for( int j = 0; j < 2; ++i )
  {
      newarray[i][j] = array[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I want that both array having the same name is there any ways to do so ? thanks

Comment: you can copy it into a newarray. and then do `array=newarray`. To copy you need to ability to refer to both source and destination , if they are both called the same it might kinda get tricy

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.copyOfRange(String param, fromIndex, toIndex)